# Is a family of commuting self adjoint operators simultaneously diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional inner product space over $\mathbb{R}$.
>
> Let $\mathscr{A}$ be a family of self-adjoint operators on $V$ such that $ST=TS$ for all $S,T\in \mathscr{A}$.
>
> Then, does there exists an orthonormal basis $\beta$ for $V$ such that $[T]_{\beta}$ is diagonal for every $T\in\mathscr{A}$?

I'm going to prove this by induction: Decopmose $V$ into the direct sum of eigenspaces, then find an orthonormal basis for each eigenspace and take a union.

Before I really write down to prove this, I want to clarify whether this is true or not. (I don't want to waste time)..

Is this $\mathscr{A}$ simultaneously diagonalizable by an orthonormal basis?

Comment: Commuting diagonalizable matrices are simultaneously diagonalizable, then use Gram-Schmidt process to make an orthonormal basis as the process preserves diagonalizability.

Comment: Hint: Try proving they share the same eigenvectors. Now, use the fact they are both diagonalizable.